# how to calculate proportion by another variable (not by frequency) in dplyr in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Using mtcars data, I want to calculate proportion of mpg for each group of cyl and am. How to calc it?

```
mtcars %>%
   group_by(cyl, am) %>%
   summarise(mpg = n(mpg)) %>%
   mutate(mpg.gr = mpg/(sum(mpg))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some sample output for one or two groups? It's not clear what you're asking at present. For each group, you want the average mpg?

Comment: What do you mean by proportion of mpg, since it's a continuous variable, not binary?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by *"not by frequency"* but maybe simply - `mtcars %>%
   group_by(cyl, am) %>%
   summarise(mpg = mpg/sum(mpg))` although this wouldn't make sense in `mtcars` context.

Comment: in another example I mean that: polulation proportion = population of districts of a city divided by total population of the city. Suppose I have variables of city (which contains info of 5 cities) and district (some city have 4 districts and some have 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the proportion of records for each combination of `cyl` and `am`. If so, then I believe your code isn't working because `n()` doesn't accept an argument. You also need to `ungroup()` before calculating your proportions.

You could simply do:

```
mtcars %>%
   group_by(cyl, am) %>%
   summarise(mpg = n()) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate(mpg.gr = mpg/(sum(mpg))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>     cyl    am   mpg mpg.gr
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     4     0     3 0.0938
#> 2     4     1     8 0.25  
#> 3     6     0     4 0.125 
#> 4     6     1     3 0.0938
#> 5     8     0    12 0.375 
#> 6     8     1     2 0.0625
```

Note that thanks to `ungroup()`, the proportions are calculated using the counts of all records, not just those within the `cyl` group, as before.

Comment: @ Felix T. Thank you for your help. But what I want is to get real value of mpg (not its counts like 3 $ 8) divide it by sum of real mpg values.